# Multiple Markers on a Google Map

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net, api, google-maps

I added a google map with two markers (i am just testing), the code is:

```
function load() {

    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));


    var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(<%=coordinates%>));
    var marker2 = new GMarker(new GLatLng(31.977211,35.951729));
    var html="<%=maptitle%><br/>" +
         "<%=text%>";
    var html2="<img src='simplemap_logo.jpg' width='20' height='20'/> " +
         "<%=maptitle%><br/>" +
         "<%=text%>" + "Alper";
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<%=coordinates%>), 5);
    map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    map.addOverlay(marker2);
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GScaleControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());


    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    marker2.openInfoWindowHtml(html2);
    }
```

The problem is, only one markers text is showing (the white triangle with text inside it) the other is not visible, why?
Another thing, i have a table of Maps, its like: mapID, mapCoordinates, mapMarkerTitle, mapMarkerText, i can retrieve this table, but i want a way to be able to pass all its records to my javascript and create a Marker for each Map i have in my table, i know this is two much, but can anyone suggest or help me with the code? as i know nothing about javascript :D

The HTML OUTPUT is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Untitled Page
</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAANgu3GlobW5KtQorgXrnJ_xTHM4EYhrvsce8mdg4KdiCoPfCQKxSOZ_5sjy4O31twg6cxfZqam24TCw"
      type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

     function load() {

    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));


    var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(32.523251,35.816068));
    var marker2 = new GMarker(new GLatLng(31.977211,35.951729));
    var html="maen<br/>" +
         " maen tamemi";
    var html2="<img src='simplemap_logo.jpg' width='20' height='20'/> " +
         "maen<br/>" +
         " maen tamemi" + "Alper";
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(32.523251,35.816068), 5);
    map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    map.addOverlay(marker2);
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GScaleControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());



    marker2.openInfoWindowHtml(html2);
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    }

    //]]>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function pageLoad() {
      }

    </script>

</head>
<body onload = "load()">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Xhome.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNDI5NDcxNTY4ZGTjxbb38769ZB2N9Ow9kAzPz2PIqA==" />
</div>

    <div id="map" style="width:400px;height:300px" >

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give us the html output produced?

Comment: check it out, i edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the second part of your question:

> i want a way to be able to pass all its records to my javascript and create a Marker for each Map i have in my table

I have (as an example - written a year or so ago) the following code:

In the code-behind I have something like this (c# I'm afraid):

```
[WebMethod]
public LatitudeLogitudeMessage[] GetPoints(string postCodes)
{
    string[] postCodeArray = postCodes.Split(",".ToCharArray());

    LatitudeLogitudeMessage[] pointArray = 
                   new LatitudeLogitudeMessage[postCodeArray.Length];
    int index = 0;
    foreach (string postCode in postCodeArray)
    {
        pointArray[index] = GetPoint(postCode);
        index++;
    }

    return pointArray;
}
```

LatitudeLogitudeMessage is a custom class that looks like this:

```
public class LatitudeLogitudeMessage
{
    public decimal? Latitude { get; set; }
    public decimal? Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public LatitudeLogitudeMessage(string addressToFind)
    {
        Address = addressToFind;
        Details = addressToFind.Replace(",", ",<br />");
    }
}
```

The GetPoint method bascially fills in those details.

In the code infront I then had:

```
PageMethods.GetPoints(address, showPoints);
```

Which calls the GetPoints method on the code behind, and passes the result to showPoints:

```
function showPoints(latLongs)
{
  GLog.write("Showing points");
  var points = [];
  var latLngBounds = new GLatLngBounds();

  for (var i = 0; i < latLongs.length; i++)
  {
    if ("" == latLongs[i].Message)
    {
      points[i] = new GLatLng(latLongs[i].Latitude, latLongs[i].Longitude);
      var marker = 
            new GMarker(points[i], {title: latLongs[i].Details, clickable: false});
      map.addOverlay(marker);
      latLngBounds.extend(points[i]);
    }
    else
    {
      GLog.write(latLongs[i].Message);
    }
  }

  if (points.length > 1)
  {
    var bounds = new GBounds(points);
    var center = new GLatLng(
         (latLngBounds.getSouthWest().lat() 
           + latLngBounds.getNorthEast().lat()) /2.,
         (latLngBounds.getSouthWest().lng() 
           + latLngBounds.getNorthEast().lng()) /2.);
    var newZoom = map.getBoundsZoomLevel(latLngBounds, map.getSize());
    map.setCenter(center, newZoom);
  }
  else
  {
    map.setCenter(points[0], defaultZoomLevel);
  }
}
```

So this takes the array of points, and iterates over them creating a marker as it goes, centering on the first item in the list (not clever, but it worked for me).

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Marker Manager API](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2006/11/marker-manager.html), it's easier to deal with. Here's the Google example:

```
function setupMap() {
 if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
   map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
   map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
   map.setCenter(new GLatLng(41, -98), 4);
   window.setTimeout(setupWeatherMarkers, 0);
 }
}

function getWeatherMarkers(n) {
  var batch = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    batch.push(new GMarker(getRandomPoint(), 
      { icon: getWeatherIcon() }));
  }
  return batch;
}

function setupWeatherMarkers() {
  mgr = new GMarkerManager(map);
  mgr.addMarkers(getWeatherMarkers(20), 3);
  mgr.addMarkers(getWeatherMarkers(200), 6);
  mgr.addMarkers(getWeatherMarkers(1000), 8);
  mgr.refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Google maps can show more than one info window at a time, so when you open the second one, the first one closes.

**Edit:** Markers also don't automatically open the information window automatically when you click on them. You need to attach a click handler to the marker that calls the showInfoWindowHtml method. I use a helper function that creates a marker and adds the click handler automatically.

```
function createMarkerHtml(point, title, html) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point, { title: title });
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() { marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html); });
    return marker;
}

map.addOverlay(createMarkerHtml(new GLatLng(<%=coordinates%>), "Marker 1", html));
map.addOverlay(createMarkerHtml(new GLatLng(31.977211,35.951729), "Marker 2", html2));
```

Comment: But the second one is not being showed at all, i close the first one and the second doesn't appear, i also click on the marker body itself, it doesn't show the information window again, not even for the one that used to show...